# Accessing a managed CacheBean in other Java Classes

Tags: java, xpages, managed-bean

I have written a Java Managed cache bean. One of the uses of this bean is to allow other parts of my app to set various databases. My template will be used by other apps, so I want to be able to set the path of the data database (my programming is in one app and my data is in another) in one place in the cache Bean and then be able to use it through out my app.

My solution seems to work, but I wonder if this is the best way to approach the problem.

My Faces-Config is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config>
  <managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>CacheBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.scoular.cache.CacheBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>application</managed-bean-scope>
  </managed-bean>
</faces-config>
```

I have paired down both the CacheBean and the other Java Class so only the relevant classes show:

CacheBean:

```
package com.xxxx.cache;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

public class CacheBean implements Serializable {

    // Constants
    private static final String BEAN_NAME = "CacheBean";

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2665922853615670023L;

    private String serverPath;
    private String pcAppDBpathJava;

    public static CacheBean getCurrentInstance() {

        // This is a neat way to get a handle on the instance of this bean in the scope from other Java code...
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); 
        return (CacheBean) context.getApplication().getVariableResolver().resolveVariable(context, BEAN_NAME);
     }

    public CacheBean() throws NotesException, Exception {
        loadDBPaths();
    }

    public void loadDBPaths() {
        Session session = Factory.getSession();
        Database tmpDB = session.getCurrentDatabase();
        String tmpStr = tmpDB.getServer();
        pcAppDBpathJava =  tmpStr + "!!" + "scoApps\\PC\\PCApp.nsf";
    }

    public String getServerPath() {
        Session session = Factory.getSession();
        Database tmpDB = session.getCurrentDatabase();
        serverPath = tmpDB.getServer();
        return serverPath;
    }

    public void setServerPath(String serverPath) {
        this.serverPath = serverPath;
    }

    public String getPcAppDBpathJava() {
        return pcAppDBpathJava;
    }

    public void setPcAppDBpathJava(String pcAppDBpathJava) {
        this.pcAppDBpathJava = pcAppDBpathJava;
    }

}
```

And the other Java class is:

```
package com.xxxx.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import org.openntf.domino.*;
import org.openntf.domino.utils.Factory;
import org.openntf.domino.xsp.XspOpenLogUtil;
import com.scoular.cache.CacheBean;

public class PC implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -928898373594997220L;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Database appData; 

    public PC() {
    }

    public void loadByUnid(String unid) {
        try {

            Database PCDataDB = this.getAppData();
            Document doc = PCDataDB.getDocumentByUNID(unid);
            if (null == doc) {
                System.out.println("Document not found");
            } else {
                loadValues(doc);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            XspOpenLogUtil.logError(e);
        }
    }

    public Database getAppData() {
        CacheBean cache = CacheBean.getCurrentInstance();
        Session session = Factory.getSession();         
            Database PCDataDB = session.getDatabase(cache.getPcDataDBpathJava());
        return PCDataDB;
    }

    public void setAppData(Database appData) {
        this.appData = appData;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your bean as "variable" from JSF engine. Take a look here: https://www.mindoo.com/web/blog.nsf/dx/18.07.2009191738KLENAL.htm?opendocument&comments

Simply call helper class for bound value and you will get either object reference or return value of some method - based on EL you use.

Update, missed actual question:

> My solution seems to work, but I wonder if this is the best way to
>   approach the problem.

Yes, I think that's the best option.

Comment: Thank you Frantisek. Your first answer confused me. I am glad that this will work.